# Select2 trigger select all checkbox

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using `Select2` dropdown, my requirement is to check uncheck checkbox value. If all options are selected then checkbox checked and if all options are not selected then checkbox uncheck.

**HTML**

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All

<input type="button" id="button" value="check Selected">
```

**JS**

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $("#e1 > option").prop("selected","selected");
        $("#e1").trigger("change");
    }else{
        $("#e1 > option").removeAttr("selected");
         $("#e1").trigger("change");
     }
});

$("#button").click(function(){
       alert($("#e1").val());
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/62/.

Comment: Please put your code into the question, a link to jsFiddle isn't enough to reproduce your question if jsFiddle goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the change event, when event fire you need check how many options chosen and compare them with all of the options:

```
$("#e1").on("change", function(e) {

    var count = this.selectedOptions.length // how options selected
    var opt = this.length; // how options total

    if (count===opt) {
        // all selected
        $("#checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        // not all selected
        $("#checkbox").prop('checked', false);        
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1834/

Comment: It provides TypeError: e.val is undefined

Comment: Strange. In what browser? However, look at an updated version.